# Why the object with the script is start moving to the right after the referenced object finished moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VideoSettings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject VideoAudioCube;
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float distanceToMove;

    private bool keepMoving = true;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Vector3 endPos;
    private bool moveBack = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        startPos = VideoAudioCube.transform.position;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (keepMoving == true)
        { 
            if (transform.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text == "Video")
            {
                StartCoroutine(MoveVideo());
            }

            keepMoving = false;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveVideo()
    {
        endPos = VideoAudioCube.transform.position - VideoAudioCube.transform.right * distanceToMove;

        if (moveBack == false)
        {
            while (VideoAudioCube.transform.position != endPos)
            {
                VideoAudioCube.transform.position =
                  Vector3.MoveTowards(VideoAudioCube.transform.position, endPos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        keepMoving = true;
        moveBack = true;
    }
}
```

In the screenshot the script is attached to the New Game cube. And the script is moving the empty GameObject parent :

The camera is facing the Buttons :

[image: New Game]

And this is after the GameObject moved for some reason I see that all the objects under Buttons start moving to the right :

It looks like the whole Buttons object is moving to the right but it's not it's only the children under buttons that move :

[image: Moving]

If I'm not using the script at all the children objects under Buttons will not move. I can't figure out what make the objects to start moving after the GameObject has finished moving.

Comment: I also can't see any reason in the script you posted .. maybe it's happening somewhere else

Comment: @derHugo I will double check again.

Comment: @derHugo He states that when he doesn't use the script, the buttons don't move. He may be mistaken or I may be missing something, but it'd imply that the script is the cause.

Comment: @DubDub I know .. but if you look at the code the only line moving anything is `VideoAudioCube.transform.position = ...` .. so why should anything else be moved by this script? Except OP didn't post the whole script here and there are more things happnening then shown here

Comment: Or @DanielLip is it maybe possible this script is multiple times in your scene and you simply referenced something wrong in `VideoAudioCube`?

Comment: @derHugo Yep, doesn't look right. As you just said it may be the case the script is used multiple times and perhaps the wrong game object is referenced.